# Difference Quotient for $\;\frac 1{x^2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

It's been a while since I've done this kind of math and I've been asked to help explain this concept to a high school student.

Given $$g(x) = {1\over x^2}$$ we are asked to find the difference quotient for

$$ {g(x) - g(3) \over x-3}, x\neq 3$$

Both the student and I arrived at the solution

$${{{1 \over x^2} - {1 \over 9}} \over {x - 3}}, x \neq 3$$

Which we were unable to simplify further. However, the textbook gives the answer as
$$-{{x + 3} \over {9 x^2}}, x \neq 3$$
I don't understand this solution and was hoping someone here could help.

(Edit: per Git Gud's comment below, moved minus sign outside the fraction in last expression)

Comment: $$\frac{1}{x^2} - \frac19 = \frac{9}{9x^2} - \frac{x^2}{9x^2} = \frac{-(x^2-9)}{9x^2} = \frac{-(x-3)(x+3)}{9x^2}$$

Comment: Do you mean $-\dfrac{x+3}{9x^2}$?

Answer (score 2):

$\require{cancel}$

> $${{{1 \over x^2} - {1 \over 9}} \over {x - 3}}, x \neq 3$$

Please note that we can simplify further, indeed:

First, let's work on the numerator:

$$\frac{1}{x^2} - \frac19 \quad =\quad  \frac{9}{9x^2} - \frac{x^2}{9x^2}\quad = \quad\frac{-(x^2-9)}{9x^2} \quad = \quad \frac{-(x-3)(x+3)}{9x^2}$$

This gives us $${{{1 \over x^2} - {1 \over 9}} \over {x - 3}} \quad = \quad \dfrac{\dfrac{-(\cancel{x-3})(x+3)}{9x^2}}{\cancel{x - 3}} \quad =\quad -\frac{(x + 3)}{9x^2}\,\;\;x \neq 3$$

Answer (score 0):

Another method, which I wish were emphasized more in high school: take your original (big) fraction, and multiply top and bottom by $9x^2$. You get:
$$
\frac{9-x^2}{9x^2(x-3)}=-\frac{x^2-9}{9x^2(x-3)}\,,
$$
in which the top now has the factor $x-3$. Cancel the common factor top and bottom, and get the claimed result.